# Making a content script that is to be injected in gmail compose page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to write a script that injects in the compose-page of gmail.

So far I've got this url-pattern: `["*://mail.google.com/*"]`. The script successfully gets injected when loading gmail, but after that it doesn't get re-injected when clicking links like inbox or compose. I was hoping `["*://mail.google.com/*compose"]` would do it easily, but no.

Is this pattern perhaps as far as I can get, and I'll then have to create a listener that checks when that part of the page is reloaded?

What is the most straightforward way to determine when the compose-page is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content script only run when a page is truly loaded.
If you want to run code for a specific hash, inject the script at the URL without the hash, and use the `hashchange` to detect changes.

```
function checkHash() {
    if (/^#(compose|drafts)\b/.test(location.hash)) {
        // Do whatever you want
    }
}
window.addEventListener('hashchange', checkHash);
checkHash();
```

Instead of monitoring the location hash, it might be more effective to use `setInterval` to continuously check whether the desired element exists in the DOM. This is particularly useful when you want to read or write the value of a specific DOM node.

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question and it works like a charm. Though I don't get why setInterval would be more suited for this? Isn't that exactly the kind of sloppy programming that generally always should be avoided? Anyway, after getting past this problem I ran into a new one. I had a working script which I ran through a bookmarklet, and for making it into an extensionI thought it would just be a matter of writing the code that would run this script, but apparently not. New question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669671/accessing-editing-the-content-of-an-iframe-from-a-chrome-extension

Comment: @Clox You need to find out when the node exists. You could either use [DOM mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) (or worse: DOM mutation events), but support is not optimal yet (though Chrome supports it, and you're writing a Chrome extension). `setInterval` is simple and universally supported. When implemented correctly, there's not a problem with it.